# MVC5 Ajax call to update database succeeds but table doesnt have new data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm at about my wits end to this. I am new to MVC5 and trying to follow this tutorial on updating my database information with Ajax but I am running into too many issues.

I have gotten to the point where my ajax call succeeds but nothing is inserted into my table.

Database name: `Company123`

Table name: `Users`

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
ID          Name          Desk_Number          Access_Level
-----------------------------------------------------------
PRIMARY AI  NULL          NULL                 NULL
```

Then I created a class for my Database as the tutorial said

```
public class Company123
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Desk_Number { get; set; }
    public double Access_Level { get; set; }
}

public class Company123Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company123> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then as the tutorial suggested I created a controller named `Company123sController` using Entity Framework which leaves me this for the Update Method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name, Desk_Number, Access_Level")] Company123 company123)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Users.Add(company123);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(company123);
}
```

Now on my `Index.cshtml` I have a script tag that is supposed to upload values via Ajax but it's not working.

```
<script>
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $name = "John";
    $deskNumber = 12.5;
    $accessLevel = 45.5;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Company123s")',
        data: { 'Name': $name, 'Desk_Number': $deskNumber, 'accessLevel': $accessLevel },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

Now I get "success" in the console but nothing is updated to my table.

**Note:**

*I didn't use the real names of my info but it's all relative. If you see an odd name then I might have slipped up and forgot to change it but it should all up good, I double checked.*

Comment: Your making an ajax call. Ajax calls DO NOT redirect so `return RedirectToAction("Index");` is pointless. Ajax calls stay on the same page so you need to update the DOM in the success callback. Alternatively do a normal submit so it does a redirect and creates a new view.

Comment: Why don't you put `try catch` there in `controller` to see if there is any `exception` when posting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code in place of your `Create action`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name, Desk_Number, Access_Level")] Company123 company123)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var context = new Company123Context())
            {
                try
                {
                    context.Users.Add(company123);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }

        return View(company123);
    }
```

It will throw an exception if there is any problem while saving a record.
Hope it will help you to debug the problem.
Basically I added `try catch block` in your code.

Comment: I tried your code. No errors on any end but still nothing uploaded to the database.

Comment: Is there anything else I could be doing wrong? I added the database connection using server explorer.

Comment: Can you put `breakpoint` at the start of this `Action` to see if control is transfered to this point from `frontend`. Then plz tell?

Comment: So I set a breakpoint there and it hit and everytime I stepped each proccess took <1ms except the `context.SaveChanges();` which took around 600.

Comment: Where you put your connection string? It should be in `Company123Context' class.

Comment: I don't think I have one. To connect to my database I did:

1. Open Server Explorer

2. Right click Data Connections and add new connection

3. Typed in my info and hit ok then I created the Entity class.

Comment: **Edit**

Added connection string:

`<add name="Company123Context" providerAName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Souce=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Company123;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSet=True"/>`

Comment: Still no errors or data being inputed, is my connection string fine? I aded it to the web.config

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Entity-Framework for database work. I don't see where you create your database context and where you dispose it. The routine should look like that:

```
using (var context = new MyDatabaseContext())
{
    var newZone = new Zone("My Zone");
    context.Zones.Add(newZone);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Try to do it like that. I suspect that something is wrong with your context, that's why your database update works incorrect.

---

I would also recommend you to debug your code as with Ajax you may not see an actual error.

Comment: I'm just using the autogenerated code by the Entity Framework with read/write permissions.

I'm sorry to ask so many questions but where would I put your above code?

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy this is database operation, you can replace your controller code that updates your database with something similar to what I posted.